# Where to find a PKG or RPM of fsarchiver?

Tags: linux, download, fsarchiver

I want to download the latest version of fsarchiver (I need a PKG file or RPM). Where can I find that?

Comment: Here, too, you need to specify your distribution (and version).

Answer (score 1):

Quoting http://www.fsarchiver.org/Installation:

> ### installation on fedora (using yum)
>
> Recent Fedora releases provide an official package for fsarchiver where all the optional features are enabled (lzma compression, encryption, ...). You can just use the following command to download and install fsarchiver and all its dependencies.
>   `yum install fsarchiver`

Comment: I have linux rht not fedora

Comment: anyway - yam not defined in my linux

Comment: @jennifer: I don't grok the difference in Fedora vs. RedHat, so I might be missing something.  And how would anyone know if you didn't specify it in the question?  Are you saying that `yum` is not installed on your box?  Did you spell the command correctly?

Comment: hi , did I need first to download the rpm file (i686)

Comment: not, if you have `yum`.  `yum install` will locate download and install the rpm package based on it's name, if it's in the distribution packages list.  If you don't have `yum`, then... I guess you have a broken system.